# Linked List issues

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I'm having a little trouble with linked lists. I don't understand why this code will traverse and print the linked list with no issue:

```
struct foo {
    int data;
    struct foo * next;
};

int main(void) {
    struct foo * bar = NULL;
    ...
    print(bar);
}

void print(struct foo * bar) {
    while (bar != NULL) {
        printf("%d, bar->data);
        bar = bar->next;
    }
}
```

Yet when I place the list inside another structure, like an array, the list gets destroyed during traversal because pointers get reassigned at `bar[i] = bar[i]->next`:

```
struct foo {
    int data;
    struct foo * next;
};

int main(void) {
    struct foo ** bar = (struct foo**)malloc(SIZE * sizeof(struct foo*));
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        bar[i] = NULL;
    ...
    print(bar);
}

void print(struct foo ** bar) {
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        while (bar[i] != NULL) {
            printf("%d, bar->data);
            bar[i] = bar[i]->next;
        }
}
```

Why does this happen? I know a proper way to write the `print` function in this scenario would be:

```
void print(struct foo ** bar) {
    struct foo * helper;
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        for (helper = foo[i]; helper != NULL; helper = helper->next)
            printf("%d", helper[i]->data);
}
```

I just want to understand *why*. Why do pointers not get reassigned in the first scenario, but do on the second? I assume it's something to do with passing values vs passing references, but that would mean the first function destroys the list too. Can anyone offer some insight?

Comment: `bar` is being passed by address (i.e. its hot). you're modifying the underlying pointer stored within your pointer array during the traversal. Invoke your original walk function with `bar[i]` as the param input and it should work as you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void print(struct foo* bar)
{
    while (bar != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d, bar->data);
        bar = bar->next;
    }
}
```

This function takes a `copy of a pointer to struct foo` as a first argument. No matter what the function does with it, I am sure that the original pointer will not be modified, since I'm just working with a copy here. The value that the pointer points to on the other hand, may be modified.

```
void print(struct foo** bar)
{
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        while (bar[i] != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d, bar->data);
                bar[i] = bar[i]->next;
        }
}
```

This function takes a `copy of a pointer to pointer to struct foo` as a first argument. Once again, the original pointer to pointer cannot be modified from here, the value which it points too on the other hand, which is a `pointer to foo` here, may be modified. Of course, the value pointed by the pointer pointed by bar, can also be modified.

If you've understood this correctly, you should realize why passing `struct something` instead of `struct something*` to a function, is a bad idea performance-wise.